# Can't draw triangle using Opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

in this code i want to draw a simple triangle on a blue background using openGL however when i compile and run the code only a window with the blue background appears (without the white triangle that is supposed to be drawn), iam using Xcode

my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#include <OpenGL/gl3.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

// VAO & VBO objects
GLuint VBO;
GLuint VAO;

void display();

// vertex Data (position)
float vertex[] = {-1.0, 0.0 , 1.0,
                   0.0, 1.0 , 0.0,
                   0.0, 0.0 , 0.0 };

GLuint Program;

GLuint Vshader;
GLuint Fshader;

// main program

int main (int argc, char *argv[])

{    

   glutInit(&argc, argv);
   glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE);
   glutInitWindowSize(1000, 400);
   glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
   glutCreateWindow("My First GLUT/OpenGL Window");
   glutDisplayFunc(display);
   glutMainLoop();


   return 0;
}



// main display function 

void display()

{
// reading the vertex shader

fstream VertexS;
VertexS.open("/Users/hawbashali/Desktop/Project X/BwlbWl/BwlbWl/vertexShader");

if(VertexS.good() == false)
    cout << "Error openning the file \n";
if(VertexS.bad() == true)
    cout << "Read/writing error on i/o operation \n";
if (VertexS.fail() == true)
    cout <<"Logical error on i/o operation \n";

VertexS.seekg(0,ios::end);
int size =  (int)VertexS.tellg();
VertexS.clear();
VertexS.seekg(0,ios::beg);

char* vBuffer = new (nothrow) char[size];

VertexS.read(vBuffer,size);

VertexS.close();



// reading fragment shader

fstream FragS;
FragS.open("/Users/hawbashali/Desktop/Project X/BwlbWl/BwlbWl/fragmentShader");

if(FragS.good() == false)
    cout << "Error openning the file \n";
if(FragS.bad() == true)
    cout << "Read/writing error on i/o operation \n";
if (FragS.fail() == true)
    cout <<"Logical error on i/o operation \n";

FragS.seekg(0,ios::end);
int size2 =  (int)FragS.tellg();
FragS.clear();
FragS.seekg(0,ios::beg);

char* fBuffer = new (nothrow) char[size2];

FragS.read(fBuffer,size2);

FragS.close();


// creating shaders

Vshader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
Fshader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

GLint x = size;
GLint y = size2;


glShaderSource(Vshader, 1,(const char**)&vBuffer, &x);
glShaderSource(Fshader, 1, (const char**)&fBuffer, &y);

glCompileShader(Vshader);
glCompileShader(Fshader);

Program = glCreateProgram();

glAttachShader(Program, Vshader);
glAttachShader(Program, Fshader);

glLinkProgram(Program);

glUseProgram(Program);



glClearColor(0, 0, 1,1);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glGenBuffers(1,&VBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,9 *sizeof(vertex),vertex, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3,GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, 0, 0);

// Drawing the triangle
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

glutSwapBuffers();

glDeleteShader(Vshader);
glDeleteShader(Fshader);

delete [] vBuffer;
delete [] fBuffer;

};
```

**Vertex shader:**

```
#version 320 core
layout(location = 0) in vec4 vPosition;
void
main()
 {
     gl_Position = vPosition;
}
```

**Fragment Shader**

```
#version 320 core
out vec4 fColor;
void
main()
{
  fColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: How, exactly, were you planning on using `#version 430 core` on OSX?

Comment: @genpfault ok now i learnt it the hard way, even if i change it back to   #version 320  the result is the same..

Answer (score 4):

```
glClearColor(0, 0, 1,1);
...
fColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
```

You're trying to draw a blue triangle on top of a blue background.  You'll have to dial up your contrast [pretty high](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity) to see that :)

Make one of them a different color, like red.

You're also:

- Missing a VAO
- Not requesting a Core context
- Using [`#version 320 core` instead of `#version 150 core`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLSL#Versions)

Try this:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Program
{
    static GLuint Load( const char* vert, const char* geom, const char* frag )
    {
        GLuint prog = glCreateProgram();
        if( vert ) AttachShader( prog, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vert );
        if( geom ) AttachShader( prog, GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER, geom );
        if( frag ) AttachShader( prog, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, frag );
        glLinkProgram( prog );
        CheckStatus( prog );
        return prog;
    }

private:
    static void CheckStatus( GLuint obj )
    {
        GLint status = GL_FALSE, len = 10;
        if( glIsShader(obj) )   glGetShaderiv( obj, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );
        if( glIsProgram(obj) )  glGetProgramiv( obj, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status );
        if( status == GL_TRUE ) return;
        if( glIsShader(obj) )   glGetShaderiv( obj, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len );
        if( glIsProgram(obj) )  glGetProgramiv( obj, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len );
        std::vector< char > log( len, 'X' );
        if( glIsShader(obj) )   glGetShaderInfoLog( obj, len, NULL, &log[0] );
        if( glIsProgram(obj) )  glGetProgramInfoLog( obj, len, NULL, &log[0] );
        std::cerr << &log[0] << std::endl;
        exit( -1 );
    }

    static void AttachShader( GLuint program, GLenum type, const char* src )
    {
        GLuint shader = glCreateShader( type );
        glShaderSource( shader, 1, &src, NULL );
        glCompileShader( shader );
        CheckStatus( shader );
        glAttachShader( program, shader );
        glDeleteShader( shader );
    }
};

#define GLSL(version, shader) "#version " #version "\n" #shader

const char* vert = GLSL
( 
    150 core,
    layout(location = 0) in vec4 vPosition;
    void
    main()
    {
        gl_Position = vPosition;
    }
);

const char* frag = GLSL
( 
    150 core,
    out vec4 fColor;
    void
    main()
    {
        fColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
);

// VAO & VBO objects
GLuint VAO;
GLuint VBO;
GLuint prog;
void init()
{
    // vertex Data (position)
    float vertex[] = { -1.0, -1.0 , 0.0,
                        1.0, -1.0 , 0.0,
                        0.0,  1.0 , 0.0 };

    glGenVertexArrays( 1, &VAO );
    glBindVertexArray( VAO );

    glGenBuffers(1,&VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 9 * sizeof(vertex), vertex, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    prog = Program::Load( vert, NULL, frag );
    glUseProgram( prog );

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0 );
}

void display()
{
    glClearColor(0, 0, 1,1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Drawing the triangle
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize(1000, 400);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitContextVersion(3, 2);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
    glutCreateWindow("My First GLUT/OpenGL Window");

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    if( GLEW_OK != glewInit() )
        return -1;

    init();

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**: Ported to GL 2.1:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Program
{
    static GLuint Load( const char* vert, const char* geom, const char* frag )
    {
        GLuint prog = glCreateProgram();
        if( vert ) AttachShader( prog, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vert );
        if( geom ) AttachShader( prog, GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER, geom );
        if( frag ) AttachShader( prog, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, frag );
        glLinkProgram( prog );
        CheckStatus( prog );
        return prog;
    }

private:
    static void CheckStatus( GLuint obj )
    {
        GLint status = GL_FALSE, len = 10;
        if( glIsShader(obj) )   glGetShaderiv( obj, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );
        if( glIsProgram(obj) )  glGetProgramiv( obj, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status );
        if( status == GL_TRUE ) return;
        if( glIsShader(obj) )   glGetShaderiv( obj, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len );
        if( glIsProgram(obj) )  glGetProgramiv( obj, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len );
        std::vector< char > log( len, 'X' );
        if( glIsShader(obj) )   glGetShaderInfoLog( obj, len, NULL, &log[0] );
        if( glIsProgram(obj) )  glGetProgramInfoLog( obj, len, NULL, &log[0] );
        std::cerr << &log[0] << std::endl;
        exit( -1 );
    }

    static void AttachShader( GLuint program, GLenum type, const char* src )
    {
        GLuint shader = glCreateShader( type );
        glShaderSource( shader, 1, &src, NULL );
        glCompileShader( shader );
        CheckStatus( shader );
        glAttachShader( program, shader );
        glDeleteShader( shader );
    }
};

#define GLSL(version, shader) "#version " #version "\n" #shader

const char* vert = GLSL
( 
    120,
    attribute vec4 vPosition;
    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = vPosition;
    }
);

const char* frag = GLSL
( 
    120,
    void main()
    {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
);

// VBO objects
GLuint VBO;
GLuint prog;
void init()
{
    // vertex Data (position)
    float vertex[] = { -1.0, -1.0 , 0.0,
                        1.0, -1.0 , 0.0,
                        0.0,  1.0 , 0.0 };

    glGenBuffers(1,&VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 9 * sizeof(vertex), vertex, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    prog = Program::Load( vert, NULL, frag );
    glUseProgram( prog );

    int posLoc = glGetAttribLocation( prog, "vPosition" );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( posLoc );
    glVertexAttribPointer( posLoc, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0 );
}

void display()
{
    glClearColor(0, 0, 1,1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Drawing the triangle
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize(1000, 400);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("My First GLUT/OpenGL Window");

    if( GLEW_OK != glewInit() )
        return -1;

    init();

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but yet this didn't solved the issue i tried the code [Here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Introduction) it worked pervectly fine, but the fact is that it doesn't use VBO or VAO, i want to use them so i become familiar with different ways of drawing in opengl, although i modified that code so it uses VBO but it is still stuck with the background color, do you have any further suggestion?? i really need help.

Comment: How did the program I posted fail on your system?  Missing triangle as before?

Comment: iam using xcode for coding which in return uses glut library not freeglut (windows implementation), my code gives error for `glutInitContextVersion(3, 2);` `glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);` error message **use of undeclared identifier** i think it is specific to freeglut not glut itself and when i comment out those lines i get the following errors  _ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '150' is not supported_
_ERROR: 0:1: '' : syntax error #version_
_ERROR: 0:2: 'layout' : syntax error syntax error_

Comment: OSX doesn't support compatibility contexts.  Either use FreeGLUT and a Core context or drop down to `#version 120`.

Comment: ok i've done as you said, now it gives me `ERROR: 0:1: '' : syntax error #version`    
`ERROR: 0:2: 'layout' : syntax error syntax error`

Comment: Sounds like you didn't rewrite the shaders to conform to `#version 120`.  See edit.

Comment: ok now this worked perfectly fine, but as you have helped me this far i want to round up alittle more information, what is the point of using `attribute` instead of `layout(position = 0)`, doen't they both serve as (an index) to specify the location of input variable to the shader?? and many thanks for your Help

Comment: `layout` isn't supported in GLSL 1.20.  So you have to use `glGetAttribLocation()` to query the shader program instead of forcing the location via `layout`.

Answer (score 0):

You have provided invalid buffer size in the following line:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 9 * sizeof(vertex), vertex, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Because `sizeof(vertex)` should return the total size of the array (e.g 36) not the underlying type, thus no need to multiply by 9. If you still want to use multiplication try following:

```
9 * sizeof(float)
```

I have to write this down... You should separate your initialization and draw cycle like in genpfault's answer.